# While iterating over stream after filter criteria how to get previous object

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to convert below code using Java Lambda, but after applying the filter *i.e.* `pinCode.getId()` how to retrieve current Address object?

```
private String getStudentState(Student[] students){
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        Student student = students[i];
        if (Utils.isValidStudent(student)) {
            Address address = student.getAddress();
            LocalAddress localAddress = (LocalAddress) address;
            PinCode pinCode = (PinCode) localAddress.getPinCode();
            if (pinCode.getId() > 12345) {
                return getState(address);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stream that you currently have? To me the question is unclear … you'd get it like anywhere else, by calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what exactly your question is. You access the address just like anywhere else: by calling the getter or storing it in a variable:

```java
students.stream()
        .filter(Utils::isValidStudent)
        .map(Student::getAddress)
        .map(LocalAddress.class::cast)
        .filter(a -> a.getPinCode().getId() > 12345))
        .map(a -> getState(a))
        .findFirst();
```